# Notation for element-wise multiplication of vector and matrix columns

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

What is a clear and concise notation for the element wise multiplication (Hadamard product) of a column vector **$v$** and each column of a matrix $F$.

What I want to achieve it this:
$$
v\odot F=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2 \\ 
v_3
\end{bmatrix} \odot 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1,1} & f_{1,2}  & f_{1,3}\\ 
f_{2,1} & f_{2,2}  & f_{2,3}\\
f_{3,1} & f_{3,2}  & f_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1f_{1,1} & v_1f_{1,2}  & v_1f_{1,3}\\ 
v_2f_{2,1} & v_2f_{2,2}  & v_2f_{2,3}\\
v_3f_{3,1} & v_3f_{3,2}  & v_3f_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is essentially the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325204/vector-matrix-element-wise-product-notation), but I don't think the answer there actually answers the question and I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Denote the all-ones vector by ${\tt1}$ and use the Hadamard product  $\;v{\tt1}^T\odot F\;$

Comment: @greg I like this solution. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elementwise/Hadamard product $(\circ)$ and the all-ones vector ${\tt1}$ can be used to write your product as
$$v\odot F = v{\tt1}^T\circ F$$
You can also write it using a diagonal matrix and the regular matrix product as
$$v\odot F = \operatorname{Diag}(v)\,F$$
as suggested in John's answer.

This is actually a special case of a more general rule, i.e.
$$ab^T\circ F = \operatorname{Diag}(a)\,F\,\operatorname{Diag}(b)$$

Comment: Thank you. I see that both $\odot$ and $\circ$ are used to denote the Hadamard product. Do you have any suggestion for another symbol that I can use for $v\ ?\ F$?

Comment: The LaTeX symbol `\star` has no standard usage in matrix algebra, so perhaps $v\star F$

Comment: The diag notation does not seem to carry to situations where $F$ is not square, does it? ($F$ and $v$ only need to agree in the number of lines.)

Comment: I might just be confused with the fact that $b$ does not have to be the same dimension as $a$. sorry if I was mistaken...

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to write this as 
$$
P = diag(v) F
$$
having first defined 
$$
diag: \Bbb R^n \to M_{nn}$$ as clearly as possible.